# Textmate, how to find out which theme I am using?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am using TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9387, I don't see any options in Preferences.

Comment: Read it http://manual.macromates.com/en/themes

Comment: I have read that manual, but I don't find a "Fonts & Colors" tab in Prefernces panel. For me, there is only: Fiels, Projects, Bundles, Variables, Software Update, Terminal. And the View->Theme menu is grey and not selectable.

Comment: Go to Bundles->Themes

Comment: Thanks for reply, but there is a list of themes, I just want to know which one I am using.

Comment: Preferences -> Fonts & Colors and see the used theme name http://manual.macromates.com/images/fonts_and_colors.png (ie MagicWill)...correct way is  View->Theme

Comment: Well, I am using a *free* version, not purchased, maybe this version is different from yours and functional limited. "View->Theme menu is grey and not selectable. " I said before.

Comment: Strange! I have to select text(use mouse) in the editor to enable the View->Theme menu. Perhaps it is textmate 2's bug.

Comment: Please add your solution to the answers and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is select View->Theme from menu bar. But I think textmate 2 has bug on that menu item, the menu item is grey and not selectable, I have to make selection of text that I am editing to enable the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an open document

Keyboard:

`Ctrl` + `Command` + `t`, begin typing `variable`, when "`Show TextMate Variables - Bundle Development`" is selected, press `return`.

Mouse:

`Bundles` → `Bundle Development` → `Show TextMate Variables`

Results:

This displays a large tooltip listing all the environment variables available to the TM, you're looking for "`TM_CURRENT_THEME_PATH`". The theme name is the same as filename in this path.

Bonus:

You could create a snippet for this as well:
Snippet/Command:

`${TM_CURRENT_THEME_PATH}`

in a snippet with a tab trigger of `theme` would cause the path to replace `theme` with the path.